# String to byte conversion

Tags: java

How can I convert a string to byte? For example, `Byte.parseByte("255");` causes `NumberFormatException` since (for some weird reason) `byte` is `signed` in java so the maximum value it can have is `127`.

So I need a function such that

```
public static byte toByte(String input) {
...
}
```

And for example `toByte("255");` should return `-1`(ie bits: 11111111)

Something like implementation of [2s complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)

Comment: erm... convert to int then cast to byte?

Comment: "for some weird reason byte is signed". As opposed to it being unsigned for some weird reason?

Comment: Its unsiged in c,c++,delphi,c#,... I think it doesnt make sense because byte is used mainly for binary data so should have no sign. If there is a need for memory-space-efficient number then there is `short`

Comment: Yea, not including an unsigned byte type is one of the mysteries that eludes me in Java.

Comment: A very similar question has been asked before and several good answers were provided.  See: ["What is the best way to work around the fact that ALL Java bytes are signed?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11088/what-is-the-best-way-to-work-around-the-fact-that-all-java-bytes-are-signed)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `Integer.parseInt("255")` and cast the resulting `int` to a `byte`:

```
byte value = (byte)Integer.parseInt("255");
```

Comment: Dam my timid nature! that should be my answer!

Answer (score 1):

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {    
     String s = "65";
     byte b = Byte.valueOf(s);
     System.out.println(b);

     // Causes a NumberFormatException since the value is out of range
     System.out.println(Byte.valueOf("129"));
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

byte value = (byte)Integer.parseInt("255");

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking of the following implementation!

```
public static byte toByte(String input) {
    Integer value = new Integer(input);

    // Can be removed if no range checking needed.
    // Modify if different range need to be checked.
    if (value > 255 || value < 0)
        throw new NumberFormatException("Invalid number");

    return value.byteValue();
}
```